# Time bracket for SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I need to select rows where timestamp is between now and 5 minutes in the past. How do I do it? Something like that:

```
select * from tableName where timestamp between sysdate and up to -5 min
```

The simpler - the better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select *
  from tableName
 where timestamp between sysdate and sysdate - interval '5' minute
```

or old style:

```
select *
  from tableName
 where timestamp between sysdate and sysdate - 5 * 60 / 86400
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') NOW
,           to_char(sysdate - 1/24/12,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') "5 min. before"
    from dual;

NOW                 5 min. before
------------------- -------------------
2011-09-15 15:11:06 2011-09-15 15:06:06
```